# Can I get working RmiServiceExporter with lazy-init?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-loading, rmi

I have legacy project with a lot of beans in several contexts. Seems like there are circular dependencies between beans and that's why most of contexts has `default-lazy-init` set to **true**.

I need export some bean via RMI, so I have folowing declarations in the context:

```
<bean id="partnershipPluginService" class="com.otr.sufd.services.security.PartnershipPluginServiceImpl" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="selectionService" ref="selectionService"/>
    <property name="editObjectService" ref="editObjectService"/>
    <property name="securityFieldsService" ref="securityFieldsService"/>
    <property name="cryptoSettingsService" ref="cryptoSettingsService"/>
    <property name="authenticationService" ref="systemAuthenticationService"/>
    <property name="configurationManager" ref="serverConfigurationManager"/>
    <property name="lifeCycleDefService" ref="lifeCycleDefService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter" depends-on="partnershipPluginService" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="registryPort" value="${rmi.port}"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="partnershipPluginService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.otr.security.synchronization.service.PartnershipPluginService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="partnershipPluginService"/>
</bean>
```

Both this beans declared as **not lazy**. I thibk, enough declare at least one `RmiServiceExporter` as non lazy to have the same behavior.
In this configuration there are one big disadvantage. It doesn't work. I have exception in context creation process

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'partnershipSystemPluginService' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [security/serverSecurityServices.xml]: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'cryptoSettingsService' while setting bean
>   property 'cryptoSettingsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'cryptoSettingsService': Bean with name
>   'cryptoSettingsService' has been injected into other beans
>   [jinnCryptoService,jinnCryptoServerService] in its raw version as part
>   of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means
>   that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This
>   is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using
>   'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for
>   example.

At first look, there is no circular dependency between `jinnCryptoService` and `jinnCryptoServerService`. If I make both `RmiServiceExporter` and `partnershipPluginService` lazy like others - context creates with no exceptions, but RMI doesn't work.
So, is any way to have context and RMI working? Thanks for helping me and wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,I found a solution.
I took a look for context's neighborhood and got a few contexts with beans like `RmiServiceExporter`. That contexts is not lazy and get started after lazy contexts with beans like `partnershipPluginService`.
I replaced `RmiServiceExporter` into new context and the problem is solved.

If you'll be in my place, please take a few looks on the problem from different angles and you find an answer.

Thanks to all, who read this post, trying to help me.